# cancel process by clicking a button

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a process in the project I wrote.  It takes time, and I want to use a progress bar.  I want to allow the user to cancel the process and the ProgressBar by clicking a button.  I do not want the user to be able to click any other controls on that form when my process is running.  If I use a thread, then the user can click other controls on the form.

Perhaps one solution is to use another form, and set the ProgressBar and cancel button on the second form. But how can I set the value of the ProgressBar according my process, which is taking part on the *first* form.

What's the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for that. Add it to your first form and on BackgroundWorker progress changed event change progress bars value. Look at example shown in documentation.

Answer (score 4):

This is best done with a dialog, it automatically makes the rest of your UI inaccessible.  Add a new form to your project and drop a ProgressBar and a Button on it.  And add a public method so you can update the progress bar from the event handler in your main form:

```
public partial class ProgressDialog : Form {
    public ProgressDialog() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void ShowProgress(int progress) {
        progressBar1.Value = progress;
    }
    private void CancelProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

You'll need to display the dialog when you start the worker:

```
    ProgressDialog dlg;

    private void RunProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        using (dlg = new ProgressDialog()) {
            dlg.ShowDialog(this);
        }
        dlg = null;
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
```

Note how it calls CancelAsync() to stop the worker so closing the dialog is enough to make it stop.  You'll need to update the progress bar:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
        dlg.ShowProgress(e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
```

And you need to automatically close the dialog when the worker completes and the user hasn't close the dialog herself:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (dlg != null) dlg.Close();
    }
```

Comment: where should I wrote the codes of that special process?I wrote them under the line" if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync(); ". then after running that process , the new form was shown enabled and nothing was shown on it.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You write them in the DoWork() event handler for the background worker.

Comment: That problem was solved but another one occurs.In that process I must access to some controls which are on the form .For excample I shoul disable a button named opB.when running the project it gives me the erron on the coltrols.For example this error:" Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'opB' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." What should I do now?

Comment: This new question was already asked hundreds of times.  Use the Search box at the upper right corner of this page.

Comment: it was aslo solved.sorry to say another one took part.Although I have set the WorkerPepotProgress and WorkerSupportCancelation of the backgroundWorker as true,but the progressbar doesn't show any thing and the user can't cancel the process

Answer (score 2):

Use a `BackgroundWorker`, this provides an API for reporting progress and cancellation.